# show that the given series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that the series:
$$
\sum _{n=1} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}}{n}
$$
I tried to use Leibniz rule but I did not succeed. Any suggestions? Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is actually a really nice summation you have found. What are the applications?

Comment: @0.5772156649... Passing the exam :D

Comment: LOL @Shlomi. Unfortunately I cant help you. The convergence of this series (if exists) is relative, not absolute, search about test on wikipedia, I dont remember now.

Comment: Try Dirichlets test!

Comment: By splitting the sum over the integers into a sum over integers on the form $3k,3k+1$ and $3k+2$ we can write the sum as $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left[\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+2}\right]$ for which the alternating test can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}}{n} &= \frac{3}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty/3} \left[ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{3n} + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{3n+1} +\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3n+2} \right]\\
&=\frac{3}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{3 n}+\frac{1}{3 n+1}  + \frac{1}{3 n+2}\right)\\
\end{align}

By the Alternating series test, the three series converge, see [Paul's](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx) for further details. Below, we deduce their summation, using integration techniques.

\begin{align}
\hphantom{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}}{n}} & \\&=
\frac{3}{2}+\left[-\frac{\log (8)}{9} \right] +
\left[ \frac{\pi \sqrt{3} + \log (8)}{9} - 1 \right] +
\left[ \frac{\pi \sqrt{3} - \log (8)}{9} - \frac{1}{2}\right] \\
&= \frac{2\pi \sqrt{3} - \log (8)}{9}.
\end{align}

Comment: In the last equation it's $[2\pi \sqrt{3} \color{red}{-} \log(8) ]/9$